# How to implicitly binding multiple Eloquent models in a single route definition?

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel9 document says:

> When implicitly binding multiple Eloquent models in a single route
> definition, you may wish to scope the second Eloquent model such that
> it must be a child of the previous Eloquent model. For example,
> consider this route definition that retrieves a blog post by slug for
> a specific user:

```
   use App\Models\Post;
   use App\Models\User;
 
    Route::get('/users/{user}/posts/{post:slug}', function (User $user, Post $post) {
    return $post;
    });
```

> When using a custom keyed implicit binding as a nested route parameter, Laravel will automatically scope the query to retrieve the nested model by its parent using conventions to guess the relationship name on the parent. In this case, it will be assumed that the User model has a relationship named posts (the plural form of the route parameter name) which can be used to retrieve the Post model.
> Blockquote

but it returns error :BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Models\User::posts()

Comment: Your user model does not have a posts relation it seems

Comment: thanks. I thought Laravel will do it automatically@lk77

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me highlight this sentence **the second Eloquent model such that it must be a child of the previous Eloquent model**

based on the highlighted sentence, you must define a `posts` relationship function in the `User` model because Laravel supposes that the second segment is the child of the first segment which means that the first segment must have a `hasMany` relationship with the second segment like so,

```
public function posts()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```